# vue 3 main.js add aos library problems

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Hi everyone I am using Aos libray in my Vue 3  project

```
import App from './App.vue'
import AOS from 'aos'
import 'aos/dist/aos.css'
import { createApp } from "vue";


const app = createApp({
    render: (h) => h(App),
    created(){
        AOS.init()
    }
});
app.mount('#app')
```

And add

```
<div data-aos="fade-up">#MY codes block<div>
```

But project not working What is the problem ?? Thanks ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem
My solution was:

```
import AOS from 'aos'
import 'aos/dist/aos.css'


createApp(App)
 .use(AOS.init())
 .mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
import App from './App.vue'
import AOS from 'aos'
import 'aos/dist/aos.css'
import { createApp } from "vue";


export const app = createApp(App)
app.AOS = new AOS.init({ disable: "phone" });

app.use(AOS).mount('#app')
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.